# Which naive Bayes?

Tags: bayesian, python, naive-bayes, scikit-learn, bayesian-network

I am attempting to use a naïve Bayes classifier in python (using scikit-learn), with two examples.  The first example has 6 classes and 2 hypotheses, the 2nd example has 2 classes and 6 hypotheses.  Here's the code:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB as nb
import numpy as np

# Example 1:  Single Bernoulli - 6 classes
X = np.array([[0 , 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 1],
           [1, 0, 0, 1],
           [0, 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0]])
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
test = [0, 0, 0, 1]
clf = nb()
clf.fit(X, y)
clf.predict_proba(test)
```

Which produces:

```
array([[ 0.12195122,  0.24390244,  0.24390244,  0.12195122,  0.12195122,
     0.14634146]])
```

The correct answer is #3, but there is a two-way tie between #2 and #3

```
# Example 2: Iterative Bernoulli - 2 classes
post = np.zeros((6, 2))
for i in range(6):
    Xy = np.array([[0 , 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 1],
           [1, 0, 0, 1],
           [0, 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 1]])
    test = Xy[i,:]
    y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    x = np.delete(Xy, i, axis = 0)
    clf = nb()
    clf.fit(x,y)
    post[i,:] = clf.predict_proba(test).ravel()
    post
```

Which produces:

```
array([[ 0.87092092,  0.12907908],
   [ 0.62780964,  0.37219036],
   [ 0.40288485,  0.59711515],
   [ 0.87092092,  0.12907908],
   [ 0.87092092,  0.12907908],
   [ 0.87092092,  0.12907908]])
```

Using the argmax of the 2nd column, this provides the correct answer (#3).

I have 2 questions:

1. Statistically speaking, what is going on?  I understand these are different formulations of the problem.  I assume these 2 models would have different graphical representations, but am not sure I can articulate them.  I think of the 2nd example as a question of "which distribution did the test case come from?" (Similar to the M&M problem in "Think Bayes").
2. Is there a way to implement the "iterative" method using scikit-learn without a for-loop?